# Can i move a doc library from one site to another

Tags: document-library

Basically we are creating a new site but keeping the old site and I want the information that is there now in this certain document library on both sites. But later I want the information added to stay on the site it is added so I cannot simply link the other site. Is there an easier way to do this other than just manually adding all the stuff again.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways.

- Manual( open both libraries with the option of open with explorer and then copy paste from old to new)
- 2nd option is save the [document library as template and create DL on new site using the template](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-document-management/2-ways-move-document-library-sharepoint-2010.htm)
- [use the export /import method](http://www.dzeee.net/sharepoint/post/2010/01/17/Copy-content-from-one-site-collection-to-another-preserving-metadata.aspx)
- Use 3rd party tools i.e ShareGate, Metalogix, Ave point.